# How can I read a value from a Stimulus controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

Rather than use Stimulus targets to fetch data, I'd like to use Stimulus values in my controller but I can't find the way to retrieve it. Any idea how I could write it? Thanks.

This works:

```
HTML:
<div data-controller="admin-invoice-form">
  <div data-target="admin-invoice-form.amountDiscountedTotal" value="100"><div>
<div>

STIMULUS:
static targets = ["amountDiscountedTotal"];

connect() {
  console.log(this.amountDiscountedTotalTarget)
  --> 100
}
```

This doesn't work:

```
HTML:
<div data-controller="admin-invoice-form">
  <div data-admin-invoice-form-amount-discounted-total-value="100"><div>
<div>

STIMULUS:
static values = { amountDiscountedTotal: Number }

connect() {
  console.log(this.amountDiscountedTotalValue);
  --> undefined
  console.log(this.data.get("amountDiscountedTotalValue"));
  --> null
}
```

Comment: What version of Stimulus are you using?

Comment: values go on the controller element https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/values

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. @LB Ben Johnston, I'm using StimulusJS 1.1.1. @Alex, that was indeed my mistake, I moved it in my controller div and it now works when I `console.log(this.data.get("amountDiscountedTotalValue"))` Thanks!